# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. after upgrading to React 18

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I upgraded from React 17 to React 18 and when doing so I got this new type error. Does anyone know exactly what changed with React 18 that would make this error appear? (I'm not asking if it's right or wrong, just want to understand what they changed compared to React 17)

React 17:

[image: No error in React 17]

React 18:

[image: Error in React 18]

The exact error I get:

[image: Screenshot of error text]

Looking at the react types we can go from `DetailedHTMLProps<TdHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableDataCellElement, HTMLTableDataCellElement>` to `TdHTMLAttributes` to `HTMLAttributes` to `DOMAttributes` where finally `children` is defined as `children?: ReactNode | undefined;`
See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fc41bdd10649879190f2997632d01f338e11c761/types/react/index.d.ts#L1376
But it was the same in React 17, so I don't understand why I didn't get an error before, but do now.

Here's the code, so you can easily copy/paste

```
<tr>
  <td>Testing unknown</td>
  <td>{'unknown'}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Testing unknown</td>
  <td>{'unknown' as unknown}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Testing unknown</td>
  <td>
    <>{'unknown' as unknown}</>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And the text of the error is

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1376, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<TdHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableDataCellElement>, HTMLTableDataCellElement>'
```

Comment: You should always post code as code, not images. Also post the full *text* of the error message, not an image of the rror.

Comment: Why would you force ts to treat a string as an unknown type?

Comment: @crashmstr Posting the code as an image makes it easier to show exactly what/where TS things the error is. Pasting it as text I don't get the red squiggles. But I've updated my question to include it as text as well

Comment: @kinduser I only do that to demonstrate the issue. In my real code I have an object where some of the members are `unknown` that I'm printing

Comment: Please provide the real structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as stated in the question, the type for `<td>` is `DetailedHTMLProps<TdHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableDataCellElement, HTMLTableDataCellElement>`

From there we can walk up the types to

```
interface DOMAttributes<T> {
  children?: ReactNode | undefined
  // ...
}
```

In React 18 we have these types relevant to `ReactNode`

```
type ReactFragment = Iterable<ReactNode>;
type ReactNode = ReactElement | string | number | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

In React 17 it looks like this

```
type ReactFragment = {} | Iterable<ReactNode>;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

The important difference is that `ReactNode` can be `{}` in React 17 thanks to the `ReactFragment` type. In React 18 `{}` was removed, causing the error in the original question.